# How to get Bamboo to recognize Angular unit tests

Tags: angular, karma-runner, bamboo

I have a Angular project using Karma unit tests. The tests run fine, and pass. This is being run in an on-prem bamboo instance.

When bamboo runs the tests it runs `ng test --code-coverage` via an npm script.

Is there a way to get bamboo to reckognise the tests? Each build just reports as a testless build.

I don't need to see the coverage in bamboo but that would be great if it's possible, I'd just really like to see the tests passing and visible through the bamboo front end.

Comment: Try seeing if you can get the JUnit Parser task to understand the output of the ng test

Comment: Thanks, I have ended up using karma-junit-reporter https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter
Then in bamboo using JUnit test parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer - thought it Des finding the karma-junit-reporter is the key part that makes my second part work:

1. Use the [karma junit reporter](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-junit-reporter) to turn the karma output into standard junit test output format (xml files).
2. Use the JUnit Parser Task to parse the JUnit output to make it part of the test results of the builds.